# How to manage code base when developing in a VM (vagrant)

Tags: git, virtual-machine, vagrant

I just wrapped my head around the basic of vagrant, but what i don't get is how to manage my codebase within the virtual machine.

Right now i have set a main repo for the vagrant config, then i have a share www/ folder in which i had a submodule containing the actual code base. So the workflow to get started would look like this:

1. git clone user@the_vagrant_config_repo
2. git submodule init
3. git submodule update ( now pulling the actual code base)
4. vagrant up

What i don't like about this is that my main code base ends up as a submodule of the vagrant config, but ideally I'd like to keep that vagrant config in a repository so that i can easly pass it around.

Are there any other/better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use good old environment variables, in this case `VAGRANT_CWD`:

> VAGRANT_CWD can be set to change the working directory of Vagrant. By default, Vagrant uses the current directory you’re in. The working directory is important because it is where Vagrant looks for the Vagrantfile. It also defines how relative paths in the Vagrantfile are expanded, since they’re expanded relative to where the Vagrantfile is found.

In this way you can keep Vagrant config and your code base in two separated repositories.